# Detecting orientation in uncertain lighting

Tags: c++, opencv, orientation, object-detection

I have to detect the exact location and orientation of a `valve` in images where the lighting is not so great. Below is the image :

[image]

Detecting the circle was pretty straight-forward. I find the contours and determine the roundness of the contours. With this method I get and approximate location the square valve :

[image]

But I need to detect just the front square part (or the top `pyramid`) of the valve. I also experimented with feature detection (ORB2 in this case) with not so satisfactory results :

[image]

Any suggestions?

**Edit 1 :** Sorry for bombarding the post with so many images. Here is an image with better illumination and with ORB2 features :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Fix the illumination and/or adjust the exposure appropriately.